# Unary operator syntax error is suggesting that "Parenthesis must be used to disambiguate operator precedence"

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am working on frequency counter algorithm and I get a ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unary operator used immediately before exponentiation expression. Parenthesis must be used to disambiguate operator precedence*** error on the following line:

```
 for(let key in counter1){
        if(!key ** 2 in counter2){  <-------this line right here is where the error occurs
            return false
        }
```

At first when I was looking this up I was just focusing on the Unary portion of the error as I am aware there is a difference between writing `!key ** 2` vs. `!key**2`, but the part that stumps me is its saying that ***Parenthesis must be used to disambiguate operator precedence*** which I understand you use parenthesis to separate operations but don't know how to apply this here. What are your alternative suggestions for this?

Comment: Are you raising !key to the power of 2, or are you doing ! ( key ** 2) ? If the first, (!key) ** 2, I'd imagine.

Comment: Yes I was trying to raise !key to the power of 2. And your suggestion worked...smdh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Parenthesis must be used to disambiguate operator precedence", because "!", "**" and "in" are all operators.

What does "!key ** 2 in counter2" mean?

"key **2 is not in counter2"?

Then it should be "!((key**2) in counter2)"

or

"The 2-** negation of key *is* in counter2"?

Then it should be "((!key)**2) in counter2".

or
"The negation of the 2-** of key is in counter2"

Then it should be "(!(key**2)) in counter2".

I *guess* the correct one is the first, but a compiler/interpreter has no way of being *sure*.

Comment: The second part is what cleared it up and it end up working out. Thank you for the clarification.